# Feasibility Question - Bulk Edit

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

Just wanna know whether it is feasible to achieve this requirement via VF.

**Background and What I did so far :**

In our Case Module we have the following four fields (Queue/Type/Area/Sub Area) that will determine the type of escalation and route it to appropriate queue.

Users are asking whether it is possible for them to be given an UI using which they can do mass changes (kinda like inline editing) on a selected list of cases using some condition and issue a save operation in one go.

My initial idea was asking them to create a list view (using whatever search critieria they want) and explore whether it is possible to do mass updates.

But the sad thing is the inline editing feature is not working in Case object in our org.

So I am tasked with finding out whether this req can be implemented via VF ?.

Any thoughts ??

Would appreciate any info :)

PS :
I am kinda new to SFSE (and even to SF)  as such I am wondering whether this forum allows or supports signatures.
Can someone let me know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List View Inline Editing won't work if you use record types, and the list view doesn't filter down to a single record type. Try updating your view filters.

Instead of Visualforce, you can also use just a normal button to call some Apex Code. That generally looks like this:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")}
try {
    sforce.apex.execute('MyClass','MyFunction',
        {recordIds:{!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Case)}});
    window.top.location.refresh();
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

See the documentation on [Apex in AJAX](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_and_ajax.htm) for more details on using this code.

In general, this allows you to use a default list view to provide extended functionality instead of having to write your own Visualforce page.

Answer (score 1):

It ought to be possible to do mass updates from a list view:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=inline_editing_in_a_list.htm&language=en_US

If that's not working, I would put my energies into fixing that rather than implementing a mass-edit page.

If you really need to write your own, though, start with this unmanaged package like this one:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ

Answer (score 0):

.    you can use wrapper class, where in you can create check boxes and check those box which is to be edited and on clock of edit button put those fields with check box true in new list and assign apex:inputfield instead of output field in this new table. Now you can edit everything you need thn on save button just update the new list.